# Recursive calls causes Java Stack Overflow

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

**Problem**

Hello,

I'm doing Java project for my university studies and encountered a problem I could not solve myself, this is the first time I'm askin a question here so tell me if I did anything wrong.

I am trying to solve a simply connected maze using a Wall follower algorithm, the algorithm walks the maze and always trys to turn right then move forward and lastly turns right. Whe encountering a dead the algorithm it will turn around and start moving back.

My recursive soution causes a StackOverflow error when the maze size is above 500 x 500. I am wondering is there a error in the code or is it just not viable to solve this kind of problem with recursive algorithm.

NOTE: The problem is not that the algorithm does not work but that it runs out of Stack!

** Question **

Is there a loop or memory leak or is it just not possible to use recursion after a certain number of calls.

I have a iterative solution that works at any maze size.

[Project repository](https://github.com/Viltska/maze-solver)

**Program**

the Maze is represented as a 2D-array and each square has its own class that holds it coordinates inside the maze. My thinking is that Java stores these Square objects without cleaning them while the recursive method is running. The move() method calls a method getSquareInDirection that creates a new Square object, that might cause the error. The other methods only alter the enum Dircetion and should not be the cause of the error, but I am not sure of this.

Parent method

```
    public SquareQue solveRecursive() {
        Square start = maze.getStart();
        SquareQue path = new SquareQue();
        move(start, Direction.DOWN, path);

        maze.setSquareValue(start.getWidth(), start.getHeight(), 3);

        return path;
    }
```

Recursive method

```
public SquareQue move(Square pos, Direction dir, SquareQue path) {
        if (maze.reachedFinish(pos)) {
            path.add(pos);
            return path;
        }

        if (canMove(pos, getDirectionToRight(dir))) {
            pos = getSquareInDirection(pos, getDirectionToRight(dir));
            path.add(pos);
            return move(pos, getDirectionToRight(dir), path);

        } else if (canMove(pos, dir)) {
            pos = getSquareInDirection(pos, dir);
            path.add(pos);
            return move(pos, dir, path);

        } else if (canMove(pos, getDirectionToLeft(dir))) {
            pos = getSquareInDirection(pos, getDirectionToLeft(dir));
            path.add(pos);
            return move(pos, getDirectionToLeft(dir), path);

        } else {
            pos = getSquareInDirection(pos, reverse(dir));
            return move(pos, reverse(dir), path);
        }
    }
```

Recrsuvie method calls this

```
public static Square getSquareInDirection(Square pos, Direction dir) {
        int col = pos.getWidth();
        int row = pos.getHeight();
        if (dir == Direction.UP) {
            return new Square(col, row - 1);
        }
        if (dir == Direction.DOWN) {
            return new Square(col, row + 1);
        }
        if (dir == Direction.RIGHT) {
            return new Square(col + 1, row);
        }
        if (dir == Direction.LEFT) {
            return new Square(col - 1, row);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Reproduce error**

Easiest way to reproduce the error is to clone the project and edit the GUI class.

Inside GUI class inside the method getSolveScene and alter the button settings for calling a large recursive result
method:

```
if (selectedString.equals("Large")) {
                    stage.setScene(getSolveScene(81, 81, 12, setting));
                    stage.setTitle("Maze generator - Recursive Large");

                }
```

Repalce the getSolveScene with for example: `(getSolveScene(501, 501, 12, setting)`.

After this you can save and run the progra with settings Large and Recursive.

Thanks in advance for responding!

Comment: you'll need to show all the relevant code (preferably in a minimal reproducible way)

Comment: Can you make your question stand out? what you're asking exactly?

Comment: How do you make sure that the code is not moving in a circle? Does the `canMove` method check if you have already visited a square?

Comment: If your recursive algorithm works for a relatively small sizes, and throws *StackOverFlow* runtime exception, it is very possible that you can improve it by the [memoization technique](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memoization-1d-2d-and-3d/). With this, you cache already calculated expressions and re-use their results for the same set of arguments.

Comment: The algorithm is not intended to directly track it's visited squares. Instead it uses the logic that by always following a wall on the right it will eventually reach the end.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive approach should work as long as your stack size is large enough to accomodate the required depth of recursion (that depends on the size of your maze).

However, I also see another problem - `getSquareInDirection` doesn't seem to be checking not to go back to the path that was already visited. If that happens, your program might get stuck in a "loop" a.k.a. infinite recursion. Try printing current coordinates in `move` and see if they repeat themselves. (Hint: they should not)

Comment: This is as intended the algorithm is not allowed to track its visited squares. The loop is avoided by reversing the traverse direction the algorithm it  will the back track to the last junction that was ignored on the first pass because at that time it was a left turn.

Comment: @VilleManninen In this case, the maze must have no loops or parallel paths, i.e. it must be a tree. Is this what you mean by "simply connected"?

Comment: Yes sorry I should have made it more clear, this is indeed what it means. To clarify the algorithm does solve the generated mazes but runs out of memory with large mazes.

Comment: @VilleManninen In this case, you have a legitimate requirement for a larger-than-default stack - just use something like `java -Xss32m` (adjust size as necessary).

Answer (score 0):

The default stack size is quite small (at least often too small for recursive algorithms). Default is in most VMs only 1MByte.

To change the stack size use the VM-parameter: **-Xss**

But to check if the stack size is your only problem, try to solve a smaller maze first.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @Giorgi Tsiklauri: I'm quite sure a recursive search in a 500x500 maze will lead to a recursion depth that can be higher than the 1MB stack size.

Comment: Yes, but that is an assumption which you bring as a part of discussion, not as an answer which clearly solves the problem.